# Dynamically deserialize a class based on a type variable with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, udp, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to create a standardised event messaging system (for my game server and client), that sends data over UDP socket using protobuf-net for fast and optimal transfer of data.

At the moment I am trying to send an event class, which could either be `PlayerIntentEvent` class or a `OnConnectionEvent` class at the moment (more events are existing, those are just an example).

I am sending a byte[] of which the first byte represents the event class (used for the deserialisation) and the rest of the byte[] is the class itself, serialized with protobuf-net. This part works fine. My problem is in the receiving part. **I want to dynamically deserialize a class based on a type variable.**

After a week of searching and trying out different things I cannot find a way of doing this.

**My current setup:**

Constants for the event types:

```
public static class EventTypes {
    public static byte OnConnection = 1;
    public static byte OnError = 2;
    public static byte OnPlayerIntent = 3;
}
```

Server's event mapping:

```
public static class Constants {

    public static Dictionary<byte, Type> EventDataCastDictionary = new Dictionary<byte, Type> {
        { EventTypes.OnConnection, null },
        { EventTypes.OnPlayerIntent, typeof (PlayerIntentEvent) }
    };

    public static readonly IPEndPoint ClientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    public static readonly IPEndPoint ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9423);
}
```

For test purposes I have created a sender method that only sends PlayerIntentEvents to the server:

```
public void SendPlayerIntent(PlayerIntentEvent packet) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                stream.WriteByte(EventTypes.OnPlayerIntent);
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<PlayerIntentEvent>(stream, packet);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            //client is an instance of UdpClient
            client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, serverEndPoint);

        } catch (Exception err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

The receiving side of my server:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProtoBuf;

abstract class UdpBase {
    protected UdpClient Client;

    protected UdpBase() {
        Client = new UdpClient();
    }

    public async Task<Received> Receive() {
        var receivedStream = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
        NetworkPacket networkPacket = new NetworkPacket();

        object packet = null;
        //Getting the class type from the first byte of the array
        Type eventType = Constants.EventDataCastDictionary[receivedStream.Buffer[0]];

        //----PROBLEM
        //Here I am reading only the class
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(receivedStream.Buffer, 1, receivedStream.Buffer.Length - 1)) {
        //I want to put a type from my mapping in place of the ?????*
        //I have tried using eventType variable, but the code does not compile
            packet = Serializer.Deserialize<?????*>(stream);
        }
        //----END OF PROBLEM    

        //The return statement is not finished
        return new Received();
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE:

After using David's modification I have started to receive

```
Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in protobuf-net.dll
Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in mscorlib.dll
```

#### UPDATE2:

I was missing a default parameterless constructor on my event class. Now everything is working, even without `Convert.ChangeType`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [non-generic overload](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/1bb4337c1d2bfe34ac35b3afd4cd76fb24f3075b/protobuf-net/Serializer.cs#L85) and cast the result:

```
Type eventType = Constants.EventDataCastDictionary[receivedStream.Buffer[0]];
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(receivedStream.Buffer, 1, 
        receivedStream.Buffer.Length - 1)) {
    packet =  Convert.ChangeType(Serializer.Deserialize(eventType, stream),
                                 eventType);
}
```

Comment: @NikolayBabanov I've updated it with a `Convert.ChangeType` call since you can't cast based off of what you have.  If there are additional errors like the exception being thrown, there is probably something incorrect about what you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: The code now compiles, but I still receive:

`Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in protobuf-net.dll`
`Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in mscorlib.dll`

This is very odd. If I do it the usual way of deserializing with a known type, everything is working correct.

Comment: When debugging, is the type what you expect it to be?  Keep in mind, you are manually modifying the stream which is probably resulting in the bad deserialization.

Comment: I am now reverting to my latest commit from git, because I have now totally broken the deserialization. I will post update as things evolve.

Comment: I was missing a default comstructor. Now your suggestion is working even without `Convert.ChangeType`. :)

Comment: Fantastic!  Happy to help and thanks for the follow up info!